# How to set screen zoom by geopoints?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, mapactivity

I drew a line between 2 geopoints. How do I set screen zoom by these 2 geopoints. What I want to do is to show start and finish points by default. Is there any algorithm for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here what I did :

```
private void centerMap() {

            int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for (Point point : twoPoints) {

                    int lat = (int) (point.getLatitude() * 1E6);
                    int lon = (int) (point.getLongitude() * 1E6);

                    maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
                    minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
                    maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
                    minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);
            }

                    mc.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon));
            mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2));
    }
```

(Where mc is your MapController)

Comment: Beware that `(maxLat + minLat) / 2` can overflow. Use `maxLat - (maxLat - minLat) / 2` instead. The same applies to the longitude.