# OSM Mapview: Show all geopoints from geotracking in the screen

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I followed the example here: [How to set screen zoom by geopoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233831/how-to-set-screen-zoom-by-geopoints)

But my problem is that my route is very small in the mapview. It should end near the borders.

This is how it looks with the code below:

[image: this is how it looks with the code below]

```
private void centerMap(ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints) {
    GeoPoint[] geoPoints = new GeoPoint[waypoints.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i<waypoints.size(); i++) {
        geoPoints[i] = waypoints.get(i);
    }

    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    //for (Point point : twoPoints) {
    for(GeoPoint point: geoPoints){
        int lat = (int) (point.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lon = (int) (point.getLongitude() * 1E6);

        maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
        minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
        maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
        minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);
    }

    mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs(maxLat - minLat), Math.abs(maxLon - minLon));
    mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat) / 2, (maxLon + minLon) / 2));
}
```

Comment: Beware that `(maxLat + minLat) / 2` can overflow. Use `maxLat - (maxLat - minLat) / 2` instead. The same applies to the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void centerMap(ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints) {
    BoundingBox bb = BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(waypoints);
    mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(bb);
}
```

And note that lat/lon values are now double by default in osmdroid.

Comment: thanx for your answer. But in my app there is the same problem with the scale. Do this work in your app?

Comment: yes, it works as long as you use it when the map is already displayed = not working during onCreate.